# Changing user input from value to key using Python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a dictionary that contains keys and values of different countries. e.g

Sample variables:

```
property = ['Hub','Country','Division']
divisionlist = ['GE']
hublist = ['EUDIV']
countrylist = ['GER', 'GRE', 'HUN']
countrynamelist = ['Germany','Greece','Hungary']
```

Code to make dictionary:

```
countrydict ={key:value for key, value in zip(countrynamelist,countrylist)}
```

Dictionary visualised:

```
countrydict = {'Germany': 'GER', 'Greece': 'GRE', 'Hungary': 'HUN'}
```

Extract from a function:

```
while True:
        print("Select between a 'Hub','Country' or 'Division'")
        first_property = input('Enter a property name: ').capitalize()
        if first_property in property:
            break
        else:
            continue
    if first_property == 'Hub':
        print('Available hubs: ', hublist)
        first_value = input('Enter a hub name: ').upper()
    if first_property == 'Country':
        country_value = input('Enter a country name: ').capitalize()
        first_value = countrydict[country_value]
    if first_property == 'Division':
        print('Available divisions: ', divisionlist)
        first_value = input('Enter a division name: ').upper()
```

I'm trying to allow users to input the name of the country instead of the acronym, as it is easier. However I'm getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello_alerts.py", line 85, in <module>
    alert()
  File "hello_alerts.py", line 50, in alert
    first_value = countrydict[country_value]
KeyError: 'Germany'
```

Comment: The code should not throw an error as you've shown us. I am not able to reproduce the KeyError using a paired down version of your code and entering "Germany" in my console when prompted for a country name.

Comment: what are the options you are entering to the program?

Comment: i ran your code without the `if first_property in property:` since you did not show us what does it contain , and it is working - Are you sure the above is your code?

Comment: Can you show the code exactly as it is. `contrydict` seems to be in a different scope. Or to put it another way - the only reason why it wont recognize 'Germany' key is that it can't see the `contrydict` in its scope

Comment: What input do you give to which it crashes?

Comment: Thanks for your answers but I just figured it out. In the files I was running the code the dictionary was built with keys first then values, this is why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the value exists in the `countrydict`, and if it does not, maybe assign a `NA` string:

```
if country_value in countrydict:
    first_value = countrydict[country_value]
else:
    first_value = "NA"
print(first_value)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Enter a country name: Germany
GER
```

Comment: this seems like a good solution although the OP did not upload a code that reproduce the error....